# Subscript an Arrary of generics type: error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[T]'

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, subscript

How to solve this problem?

```
protocol Mappable {
    ...
}
class Foo {
    item:AnyObject
}
class SomeClass<T:Mappable> {
    var someObject = Foo()
    var items:[T]
    ...
    func someFunction() {
        someObject.item = items[index] // error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[T]'
    }
```

I've tried adding an extension for subscripting `[T]` but fail:

```
extension Array where Element:Mappable {
    subscript(index: Int) -> Element? {
        return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: This is a misleading error message, please see answers below**

Comment: The error message is misleading. Just add a return type to the method. The extension is not needed.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question. The SO format is question+answer(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't so much about subscripting. It's about type conversion. Swift gave a misleading error message. Take a look at this line:

```
someObject.item = items[index]
    AnyObject ^   ^ Mappable
```

Swift doesn't implicitly convert `Mappable` to `AnyObject`. Instead you must use a force cast:

```
func someFunction() {
    // Assuming `index` is an Int
    someObject.item = items[index] as! AnyObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is just the small change in your class. Just look at that!

```
class SomeClass<T: Mappable>{
    var items:[T] = []
    func getSomeItem(index:Int) -> T{
        return self.items[index] as T // no error
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Side note: `as T` is redundant, the compiler knows the type